# Is it possible to create a file on the client side using JavaScript/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is it possible to generate a file on client side using Javascript/AJAX and the server side response (a string, for example) and then open this file download window? A simple `.txt`, for example.

And if it is possible, is there any solution which generates `.xlsx` files?

Comment: no, JS can't access the filsystem, but depending on the filetype you want to create and what you want to do with it, you may be able to generate a dataURI for a file..

Comment: And sure: Ajax is not for this ^^ it was just for curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

This will create a CSV that you can open in excel based on an array of objects (window.EXPORTDATA):

```
        var csvContent = [];

        for(var i=0; i<window.EXPORTDATA.length; i++){
          var rowContent = [];
          var row = window.EXPORTDATA[i];
          if(csvContent.length === 0){
            for(var p in row)
              if(row.hasOwnProperty(p))
                rowContent.push('"'+ (""+p).replace('"','').replace(',','') +'"');
            csvContent.push("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"+rowContent.join(","));
            rowContent = [];
          }
          for(var p in row){
            if(row.hasOwnProperty(p))
              rowContent.push('"'+ (""+row[p]).replace('"','').replace(',','') +'"');
          }
          csvContent.push(rowContent.join(","));
        }

        var dat = csvContent.join("\n");
        var encodedUri = encodeURI(dat);
        window.open(encodedUri);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efpgvjfq/).. when you run it it will ask you to open the file in Excel or whatever you use..